# Having trouble finding sprite on canvas of html5 game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite, scene

I am new at learning coding and game development. I have attempted to make a HTML5 simple game based off my online instructor's. Looking though my html coding, I believe it is exactly how my instructor did it. Problem is that I cannot seem to find my sprite.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tico's Flight</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="simpleGame.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var scene;
    var bird;
    function init() {
      scene = new Scene();
      bird = new Sprite(scene, "birdgame.png", 50, 50);
      bird.setAngle(270);
      bird.setSpeed(0);
      scene.start();
    }

    function update() {
      scene.clear();

      if (keyDown[K_UP]) {
        bird.setSpeedBy(1);
      }
      if (keyDown[K_DOWN]) {
        bird.changeSpeedBy(-1);
      }
      if (keyDown[K_LEFT]) {
        bird.changeAngleBy(-5);
      }
      if (keyDown[K_RIGHT]) {
        bird.changeAngleBy(5);
      }

      bird.update();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <center>
    <h1>Fly Tico!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `Scene` is `undefined`. Is that in `simpleGame.js`? Can't see it.

Comment: This is code on simpleGame.js file about Scene my instructor pre-made:

function Scene(){
    //Scene that encapsulates the animation background

    //determine if it's a touchscreen device
    this.touchable = 'createTouch' in document;
    
    //dynamically create a canvas element
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    this.clear = function(){
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }

Comment: Sorry, I am new here and so I'm learning how to use. Formatting code...

`function Scene(){
    //Scene that encapsulates the animation background

    //determine if it's a touchscreen device
    this.touchable = 'createTouch' in document;
    
    //dynamically create a canvas element
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    this.clear = function(){
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Something simple, as I am learning it usually is: I typed "keyDown" instead of "keysDown". Got my bird visible and flying around.